# Cumulant of an Autocorrelation Function

Tags: probability, statistics

If we have a random variable $x$ with probability distribution $p(x,t)$ we can define the moment generating function $$P(k,t)=\int dx e^{ikx}p(x,t)$$ From this one can compute the moments via the expression $$\langle x^n\rangle=\frac{1}{i^n}\frac{d^n}{dk^n}P(k,t)|_{k=0}$$ The cumulants are defined via the expansion $$lnP(k)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(ik)^n}{n!}\langle x ^n\rangle_{c}$$ For example the first cumulant $\langle x \rangle_{c}=\langle x\rangle$ whilst the second cumulant $\langle x^2 \rangle_c$ is the variance.

However I have come across a cumulant of an autocorrelation function $$\langle x (t)x(t')\rangle _{c}$$ Would anybody be able to explain what this would actually correspond to and how it fits the above definitions? Thanks!

Comment: What is the notation $\langle x \rangle$? Also, the integral you have written, we usually call the *characteristic function*. The moment generating function is without the imaginary $i$.

Comment: $\langle x^n \rangle$ is the mean of $x^n$, whereas $\langle x^n \rangle_c$ is the $n$th cumulant of $x$.

Comment: I think the answer is $\langle x(t)x(t') \rangle - \langle x(t) \rangle \langle x(t') \rangle$ but not too sure why

Comment: By your notation, an autocorrelation function is usually given as $\gamma(t,t') = \bigl\langle \bigl(x(t) -\langle x(t) \rangle \bigr) \bigl(x(t') - \langle x(t') \rangle\bigr) \bigr \rangle / \bigl( \langle x^2(t) \rangle \langle x^2(t')\rangle \bigr)^{1/2}$. Are you trying to find the cumulant of this? Also, I take it that by *mean*  you mean *expectation*.

Comment: I would just like to find the cumulant of the quantity in the OP, even if it is not actually called an autocorrelation function. Also, yes :)